# The bloc state does not work when entering the application - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

When I enter the application, a status check (todo_list) should be performed. If there is no list, then it should write **No Todo**, if there is, then it should load. In my case, if there is no data in the DB, then just a black screen without text. Accordingly, it turns out that the check does not occur, or what could be the reason? I will be grateful :)

**todo_bloc**

```
  class TodoBloc extends Bloc<TodoEvent, TodoState> {
  final TodoRepository todoRepository;

  TodoBloc(this.todoRepository) : super(TodoEmptyState()) {
    on<LoadTodos>((event, emit) async {
      emit(TodoLoadingState());
      try {
        final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
        emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
      } catch (_) {
        emit(TodoErrorState());
      }
    });
```

**todo_state**

```
abstract class TodoState extends Equatable {
  const TodoState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class TodoEmptyState extends TodoState {}
```

**todo_list**

```
    class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TodoList> createState() => _TodoListState();
}

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(LoadTodos());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                  shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 8),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 0.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  borderOnForeground: false,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${state.loadedUser[index].description}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21.0,
                              // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          // Text('${state.loadedUser[index].id}'),
                        ]),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      tooltip: 'Delete Todo',
                      highlightColor: Colors.red,
                      onPressed: () {
                        todoBloc
                            .add(DeleteTodos(id: state.loadedUser[index].id));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
                            todo: state.loadedUser[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ));
      }
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

1 element at index 0 is transferred to the debug into the TodoLoadedState state, although I did not create it, and maybe because of this the TodoEmptyState state does not work?

[image]

Comment: Are you adding the event? Could you show your full `TodoBloc` constructor and `build` method?

Comment: ok, fully added build method and todo_bloc

Comment: Is it possible you got an error while fetching the todos? Could you add `print(_)` on your catch on your `TodoBloc`?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parameter `listen: false`, while accessing the provider in your initState as:

```
BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context,listen:false).add(LoadTodos());
```

This is because if you want to access provider in your initState, you should set the listen parameter to false.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it did not help, it still does not show "No Todo"

Comment: Is there any error on the console?

Comment: todo_list in your question doesn't contain the full code, please update it. Also context.read inside build function is not recommended!

Comment: There are no errors, immediately when it enters the application - it does not write anything. Added all code todo_list

Comment: and what to use instead of context.read?

Comment: Since I could not run your code, the situation here might have been that TodoEmptyState() is returned as an initial state from the bloc, and LoadTodos() is called in the initState method, which tries to fetch the todos and returns either TodoLoadedState() or TodoErrorState(), so even if 'No Todo' had been displayed, this might have been replaced quickly by another state and so you are not seeing 'No Todos'.

Comment: Also please, try returning a different widget for TodoErrorState() inside BlocBuilder, as todo bloc might have thrown an error and that might be the reason you are seeing the black screen.Also check the state that is being received in the BlocBuilder widget.

Comment: Use context.watch so that you could get notified when the value changes and you can always have the latest updated value to work with. If you need the provider value for any kind of action like on onPressed, onTap, etc. access the provider value inside those functions so that you extract the latest value whenever you need it!

Comment: I'll try to do so. Thank you :)

Comment: The code was not run because some files are missing here, such as the repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241224/discussion-between-max-zubko-and-suvash-bhandari).